# Why am I getting this error when trying to update an Access Database file (.mdb) with a Datatable:

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable, dataset, oledbcommand

I've been working on my issue for 30 hours. Each time I fix one thing a new error arises. All I want to do is take a DataTables from memory and simply update an Access .MDB file. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LCR_ShepherdStaffupdater_1._0
{
    public class DatabaseHandling
    {
        static DataTable datatableB = new DataTable();
        static DataTable datatableA = new DataTable();
        public static DataSet datasetA = new DataSet();
        public static DataSet datasetB = new DataSet();
        static OleDbDataAdapter adapterA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        static OleDbDataAdapter adapterB = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        static string connectionstringA = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Settings.getfilelocationA();
        static string connectionstringB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Settings.getfilelocationB();
        static OleDbConnection dataconnectionB = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringB);
        static OleDbConnection dataconnectionA = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringA);
        static DataTable tableListA;
        static DataTable tableListB;

        static public void addTableA(string table, bool addtoDataSet)
        {
            dataconnectionA.Open();
            datatableA = new DataTable(table);
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand commandselectA = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]", dataconnectionA);
                adapterA.SelectCommand = commandselectA;
                adapterA.Fill(datatableA);
            }
            catch
            {
                Logging.updateLog("Error: Tried to get " + table + " from DataSetA. Table doesn't exist!", true, false, false);
            }

            if (addtoDataSet == true)
            {
                datasetA.Tables.Add(datatableA);
                Logging.updateLog("Added DataTableA: " + datatableA.TableName.ToString() + " Successfully!", false, false, false);
            }

            dataconnectionA.Close();
        }

        static public void addTableB(string table, bool addtoDataSet)
        {
            dataconnectionB.Open();
            datatableB = new DataTable(table);

            try
            {
                OleDbCommand commandselectB = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]", dataconnectionB);
                adapterB.SelectCommand = commandselectB;
                adapterB.Fill(datatableB);
            }
            catch
            {
                Logging.updateLog("Error: Tried to get " + table + " from DataSetB. Table doesn't exist!", true, false, false);
            }



            if (addtoDataSet == true)
            {
                datasetB.Tables.Add(datatableB);
                Logging.updateLog("Added DataTableB: " + datatableB.TableName.ToString() + " Successfully!", false, false, false);
            }

            dataconnectionB.Close();
        }

        static public string[] getTablesA(string connectionString)
        {
            dataconnectionA.Open();
            tableListA = dataconnectionA.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            string[] stringTableListA = new string[tableListA.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < tableListA.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringTableListA[i] = tableListA.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            }
            dataconnectionA.Close();
            return stringTableListA;
        }

        static public string[] getTablesB(string connectionString)
        {
            dataconnectionB.Open();
            tableListB = dataconnectionB.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            string[] stringTableListB = new string[tableListB.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < tableListB.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringTableListB[i] = tableListB.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            }
            dataconnectionB.Close();
            return stringTableListB;
        }

        static public void createDataSet()
        {

            string[] tempA = getTablesA(connectionstringA);
            string[] tempB = getTablesB(connectionstringB);
            int percentage = 0;
            int maximum = (tempA.Length + tempB.Length);

            Logging.updateNotice("Loading Tables...");
            Logging.updateLog("Started Loading File A", false, false, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempA.Length ; i++)
            {
                if (!datasetA.Tables.Contains(tempA[i]))
                {
                    addTableA(tempA[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
                else
                {
                    datasetA.Tables.Remove(tempA[i]);
                    addTableA(tempA[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
            }
            Logging.updateLog("Finished loading File A", false, false, true);
            Logging.updateLog("Started loading File B", false, false, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempB.Length ; i++)
            {
                if (!datasetB.Tables.Contains(tempB[i]))
                {
                    addTableB(tempB[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
                else
                {
                    datasetB.Tables.Remove(tempB[i]);
                    addTableB(tempB[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
            }
            Logging.updateLog("Finished loading File B", false, false, true);
            Logging.updateLog("Both files loaded into memory successfully", false, true, false);


        }

        static public DataTable getDataTableA()
        {
            datatableA = datasetA.Tables[Settings.textA];

            return datatableA;
        }
        static public DataTable getDataTableB()
        {
            datatableB = datasetB.Tables[Settings.textB];
            return datatableB;
        }

        static public DataSet getDataSetA()
        {
            return datasetA;
        }

        static public DataSet getDataSetB()
        {
            return datasetB;
        }

        static public void InitiateCopyProcessA()
        {
            DataSet tablesA;
            tablesA = DatabaseHandling.getDataSetA();

                foreach (DataTable table in tablesA.Tables)
                {
                    OverwriteTable(table, table.TableName);
                    Logging.updateLog("Copied " + table.TableName + " successfully.", false, true, false);
                }

        }

        static void OverwriteTable(DataTable sourceTable, string tableName)
        {
            using (var destConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringA))
            using (var destCmd = new OleDbCommand(tableName, destConn) { CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect })
            using (var destDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(destCmd))
            {
                // Since we're using a single table, we can have the CommandBuilder
                // generate the appropriate INSERT and DELETE SQL statements
                using (var destCmdB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(destDA))
                {
                    destCmdB.QuotePrefix = "["; // quote reserved column names
                    destCmdB.QuoteSuffix = "]";
                    destDA.DeleteCommand = destCmdB.GetDeleteCommand();
                    destDA.InsertCommand = destCmdB.GetInsertCommand();

                    // Get rows from destination, and delete them
                    var destTable = new DataTable();
                    destDA.Fill(destTable);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in destTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                    }

                     destDA.Update(destTable); // !!! Run-time error: Syntax error in FROM clause. !!!

                    // Set rows from source as Added, so the DataAdapter will insert them
                    foreach (DataRow dr in sourceTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.SetAdded();
                    }
                    destDA.Update(sourceTable);
                }
            }
        }



        }          
    }
```

**EDIT:**

OKAY THANK YOU! But like-wise a new problem arose. Same source code, but as I was copying tables to the .MDB file, 10 or so tables had already been copied then I get this run-time error:

**Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.**

On this command **destDA.DeleteCommand = destCmdB.GetDeleteCommand();**

This should be my last problem and my project will be complete.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to determine what SQL is being ran (assuming the syntax error is coming from the database)?

Comment: You need to run a trace (or run that update code through the debugger), and find out what it's generating when you run that code.  My guess is that you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: New error now...no clue what it means.

Comment: The table that's being copied has no Primary Key would be my guess?

Comment: Time for a new question.

Comment: Why is everyone recommending the use of SQL Server tools (SQL Profiler, trace) when the code is running against MS Jet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
destCmdB.QuotePrefix = "["; // quote reserved column names
destCmdB.QuotePrefix = "]";
```

QuotePrefix twice?  Perhaps that could be an issue.

Comment: Yeah, the table need to have a primary key AND you need to specify it in the code.  The delete command uses it to determine which row(s) to delete.

Answer (score 2):

> Dynamic SQL generation for the
>   DeleteCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return
>   any key column information.

You need a primary key...

In your Access table you need to designate a column that contains an unique value. The primary key is used to identify an individual row. Usually you create an "ID" column that is defined as autonumber.

Comment: Awhhh crap. That sounds hard to do. I have no idea how to do that. Should I open up a new question and ask how to do that? Google isn't giving me any good examples

Answer (score 1):

```
destCmdB.QuotePrefix = "["; // quote reserved column names
destCmdB.QuoteSuffix = "]";
```

I could only find this typo.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to dump out the SQL?  If you can do that, you should be able to spot the problem.